# Changing the font size of valueBoxes

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to change the font size of the value and the subtitle for `valueBox`es.

Below is my attempt, but would be grateful of any suggestions on how to change it in a way that looks similar to the default look. Below is my reporducible example.

```
require(shinydashboard)

valueBox2 <- function (value,header_val=4, subtitle, icon = NULL, color = "aqua", width = 4, 
                       href = NULL) {
  shinydashboard:::validateColor(color)
  if (!is.null(icon)) 
    shinydashboard:::tagAssert(icon, type = "i")
  boxContent <- div(class = paste0("small-box bg-", color), 
                    div(class = "inner", eval(parse(text=paste0('h',header_val,'(',shQuote(value),')'))), p(subtitle)), if (!is.null(icon)) 
                      div(class = "icon-large", icon))
  if (!is.null(href)) 
    boxContent <- a(href = href, boxContent)
  div(class = if (!is.null(width)) 
    paste0("col-sm-", width), boxContent)
}

ui = dashboardPage(title='hello',
  dashboardHeader(title='hello2'),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput('hval',label='header value',min=1,max=6,value=3)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    valueBoxOutput('tmp')
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$tmp <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox2(value='90k',header_val = input$hval, subtitle='some long descritptive text',icon=icon("car"))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hi you can change font size directly in `valueBox` with a `p` tag without rewriting `valueBox` function (if you want you can, just wrap `value` and `subtitle` args in `tags$p`), try :

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

# header
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Changing the font size of valueBoxes", titleWidth = 450)

# sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)

# body
body <- dashboardBody(
  valueBox(
    value = "90k",
    subtitle = "some long descritptive text",
    icon = icon("car")
  ),
  valueBox(
    value = tags$p("90k", style = "font-size: 150%;"),
    subtitle = tags$p("some long descritptive text", style = "font-size: 150%;"),
    icon = icon("car fa-lg")
  ),
  valueBox(
    value = tags$p("90k", style = "font-size: 200%;"),
    subtitle = tags$p("some long descritptive text", style = "font-size: 200%;"),
    icon = icon("car fa-2x")
  ),
  valueBoxOutput(outputId = "mybigbox")
)

# server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mybigbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = tags$p("90k", style = "font-size: 300%;"),
      subtitle = tags$p("some long descritptive text", style = "font-size: 300%;"),
      icon = icon("car fa-3x")
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body), server = server)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you, one quick question, is there a way to change the colour to a non-standard colour by using a hexcolour code rather than "blue" or "aqua"?

Comment: Not with `shinydashboard`, you can with CSS, but it's not pretty : `.small-box { background-color: #FFFF00 !important; color: #000000 !important; }`

Comment: Thanks, one thing I've noticed is that you didn't use `valueBoxOutput` and `renderValueBox` ...this allows them to be dynamic...where as your method is quite fixed...can you recommend an adjustment?

Comment: Is there a way I can change the font size for all valueBoxes in my app? I tried 'tags$p(tags$style(HTML(".small-box {font-size: 10px}")))'in the DashboardBody() but does not work