# Make infobox font size adapt dynamically to content length

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am passing an input selection through to an infobox, using shinydashboard. I am encountering an issue because some of the inputs are short and some are a bit longer. Ideally I want the text to fill the box, but if I set it to the right size for something quite short, then the longer text expands the box in an untidy way. My current approach is therefore to keep the text smaller, but that does mean that when the short input is selected, it is quite diminutive-looking.

I learnt how to change text size with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441732/changing-the-font-size-of-valueboxes). However, this sets the size in a way that doesn't respond to different inputs - so presumably the percentage relates to the default size rather than to the box dimensions.

Possibly CSS? Simply because so much styling goes that way - but I'm not very proficient here. Or possibly some sort of `if` statement, or using `conditionalPanel` or `validate` - but I'm not sure what the logic would be? I have tried without any luck on those (and my attempts have been quite bulky anyway).

Example code (with text on the larger size):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  selectInput(
  "text_select", label = "Please select",
  choices = c("Short", "A longer option to choose")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(infoBoxOutput("selected")
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$selected<- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox(title = "Selected", 
            value = tags$p(input$text_select, 
                           style = "font-size: 190%;"), 
            icon = icon("bullseye"), color = "red")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```